# Can anyone please help me solve this?? (solving year 2000 with java)

Tags: java

I have a project in school to solve year 2000 with java. here is the description of the assignment:

Create a Date object with the following:
attribute:  a julian date representing the number of days since Jan 1, 1501 (the epoch date for this project) - this should be a private member variable of the class with the associated accessor and mutator methods.
constants:  a suitable constant for each month
                    a suitable contant for each component of the epoch date
method: Date(long year, long month, long day) that converts the given year, month, and day to the julian date.
method:  a method that converts a year, month, and day into the number of days since the project's epoch date.
method: a method that determines if a given year is a leap year
method: a method that returns the number of days in a given year; replace the current simple if statement with a single statement using the conditional operator (? :)
method: a method that returns the number of days in a given month of a given year; method should implement a switch statement using appropriate constants.
methods:  any of the other methods developed in class should probably also be included.
method: returnYear() a method that determines the year component of the julian date value
method: returnMonth() a method that determines the month component of the julian date value
method: returnDay() a method that determines the day component of the julian date value
method: returnMonthName() a method that returns the name of the given month ( if month = JAN return "January" (use a switch statement))
method: returnDate() a method that returns the date in the format monthName day, year
class: Utility containing two query methods.

And here is the code I came with so far.. it is not compiling because there is something wrong with the switch!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Date
{

    public final static long EPOCHYEAR = 1501;
    private long julianDate;

    Date(long year, long month, long day)
    {

        julianDate = returnTotalJulianDay(year, month, day);
        System.out.println("Days is " + julianDate);
    }

    boolean isLeapYear(long year)
    {
        boolean answer;

        if(year % 4 == 0 && (year % 4 == 0 || year % 100 != 0))
        {
            answer = true;
        }
        else
        {
            answer = false;
        }

        return answer;
    }

    long returnDaysInMonth(long year, long month)
    {

        if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
        {
            return 31;
        }
        else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        {
            return 30;
        }
        else if(isLeapYear(year))
        {
            return 29;
        }
        else
        {
            return 28;
        }
    }

    long returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day)
    {
        long julianDate;
        long monthCounter;

        julianDate = 0;
        monthCounter = 1;

        while(monthCounter < month)
        {

            julianDate += returnDaysInMonth(year, monthCounter);

            monthCounter += 1;

        }

        julianDate += day;

        return julianDate;
    }

    long returnTotalJulianDay(long year, long month, long day)
    {
        long totalJulianDay = 0;
        long yearCounter = 1;

        while(yearCounter < year)
        {

            totalJulianDay += returnJulianDate(year, month, yearCounter);

            yearCounter += 1;

        }

        return totalJulianDay;
    }

    long returnDaysInYear(long year)
    {
        final long DAYSINYEAR = 365;

        if(isLeapYear(year))
        {
            return 366;
        }
        else
        {
            return DAYSINYEAR;
        }
    }

    long returnJulianEpochDays(long year, long month, long day)
    {

        long yearCounter = EPOCHYEAR;
        long total = 0;

        while(yearCounter < year)
        {

            total += returnDaysInYear(yearCounter);

            yearCounter += 1;
        }

        total += returnJulianDate(year, month, day);

        return total;
    }

    long returnYear()
    {
        long dayCounter = 0;
        long yearCounter = EPOCHYEAR;

        for(dayCounter = this.julianDate; dayCounter > returnDaysInYear(yearCounter); yearCounter++)
        {
            dayCounter -= returnDaysInYear(yearCounter);
        }

        return yearCounter;
    }

    long returnMonth()
    {
        long julianEpochDays = julianDate;
        long yearCounter = EPOCHYEAR;
        long monthCounter = 1;

        while(julianEpochDays > returnDaysInYear(yearCounter))
        {
            julianEpochDays -= returnDaysInYear(yearCounter);
            yearCounter++;

        }

        while(julianEpochDays > returnDaysInMonth(yearCounter, monthCounter))
        {
            julianEpochDays -= returnDaysInMonth(yearCounter, monthCounter);
            monthCounter++;

        }

        return monthCounter;
    }

    long returnDay()
    {
        long julianEpochDays = julianDate;
        long yearCounter = EPOCHYEAR;
        long monthCounter = 1;

        while(julianEpochDays > returnDaysInYear(yearCounter))
        {
            julianEpochDays -= returnDaysInYear(yearCounter);
            yearCounter++;

        }

        while(julianEpochDays > returnDaysInMonth(yearCounter, monthCounter))
        {
            julianEpochDays -= returnDaysInMonth(yearCounter, monthCounter);
            monthCounter++;

        }

        return julianEpochDays;
    }

    long returnMonthName()
    {
        int month = 0;

        final int JAN = 1;
        final int FEB = 2;
        final int MAR = 3;
        final int APR = 4;
        final int MAY = 5;
        final int JUN = 6;
        final int JUL = 7;
        final int AUG = 8;
        final int SEP = 9;
        final int OCT = 10;
        final int NOV = 11;
        final int DEC = 12;

        switch(month)
        {

            case JAN:
                return "January";
            case FEB:
                return "Febuary";
            case MAR:
                return "March";
            case APR:
                return "April";
            case MAY:
                return "May";
            case JUN:
                return "June";
            case JUL:
                return "July";
            case AUG:
                return "August";
            case SEP:
                return "September";
            case OCT:
                return "October";
            case NOV:
                return "November";
            case DEC:
                return "December";

        }
    }
}

class utility
{

    public char queryForCharacter(String prompt)
    {
        int typedCharacter = ' ';

        try
        {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            typedCharacter = System.in.read();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

        return (char) typedCharacter;
    }

    public static long queryForLong(String prompt)
    {
        Scanner keyboard;
        long theNumber;

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(prompt);
        theNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        return theNumber;
    }
}

public class DateDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Date aTestDate = null;
        aTestDate = new Date(1502, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: check your error log .. what does it say? or does it show error while compiling?

Comment: You should indent your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `returnMonthName()` is declared to return a long, but the switch cases return Strings.

Also, the method needs to return something if none of the cases in the `switch` match.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy! I changed long to String in the method returnMonthName() but now its says : "variable month might not have been initialized" for this line " switch (month) {" ??

Comment: You must have modified the method returnMonthName() since your example code above. In your example above, 'month' is initialized to zero in the very first statement in the method. In your modification, check that you've initialized it to a value before trying to use it. Also, welcome to StackOverflow. You can upvote multiple answers by clicking the up-arrow to their left. You can accept one answer as the best by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Comment: Thanks again Andy! I wanted to upvote your comment but it requires at least 15 reputation lol
Now I did initialize the month to zero and its compiling but the method doesn't work. it returns only zero for the month. do you have any clue?

Comment: Where do you set the month to something other than zero? (Hint: consider passing the month as a parameter to the method.)

Comment: At the very last line in the code I posted (DateDriver). I wanted to test it so I set the month to 1 which should be January but it returns only the number zero...

Comment: Okay, in the example code you're not passing that particular month anywhere. Identify where the month starts, and how it gets where you want it to go.

Comment: Oh Oh I got it! Million thanks Andy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a type of long:

"long returnMonthName() {"

But your are returning a type of "String".  i.e. "January".

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcsumus! I changed long to String in the method returnMonthName() but now its says : "variable month might not have been initialized" for this line " switch (month) {" ??